# How to format the text in text editor project in java?

Tags: java

How to format the text in text editor project? When I try to format the text it is appling for
entire file. I Want to apply only for selected text only. I want show the text in multiple styles like ( times new roman, arial, etc) and multiple font size(10, 12, 14 , 16 etc).

Comment: Is text editor project an application?

Answer (score 2):

I found this nice Example, [www.java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneExtendedParagraphExample.htm).

Hope this is what you want to do.